# WSO2 Identity Server 5.5.0 - Self contained access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 identity server 5.5.0 as a key manager for WSO2 API manager 2.2.0, I want to access the resources using the self-contained access token by following the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Self-contained+Access+Tokens). I am able to fetch the Access token using JWT access token. But when I try to invoke the API's created in the store using the Access token, the Identity server is throwing an exception, below is the stack trace

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2TokenValidationService} -  Error occurred while validating the OAuth2 access token
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error while getting access token hash.
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.TokenValidationHandler.findAccessToken(TokenValidationHandler.java:504)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.TokenValidationHandler.findOAuthConsumerIfTokenIsValid(TokenValidationHandler.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2TokenValidationService.findOAuthConsumerIfTokenIsValid(OAuth2TokenValidationService.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.findOAuthConsumerIfTokenIsValid(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:746)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getTokenMetaData(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:403)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler.validateToken(DefaultKeyValidationHandler.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:232)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: Error while getting access token hash
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer.getAccessTokenHash(JWTTokenIssuer.java:147)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.TokenValidationHandler.findAccessToken(TokenValidationHandler.java:492)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Invalid JWT serialization: Missing dot delimiter(s)
        at com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser.parse(JWTParser.java:44)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.JWTTokenIssuer.getAccessTokenHash(JWTTokenIssuer.java:141)
        ... 68 more
[2019-05-14 12:52:33,282] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl} -  Invalid OAuth Token : Error while getting access token hash.
```

Please help me, what configuration step I have missed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using JWT instead of OAuth2 token?

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 API manager 2.2.0, securing the APIs is supported only through the access tokens. If you are using IS as KM with APIM, you can't use the JWT from the KM directly to protect your APIs.

But If you really want, you can have the IS as an Identity provider for APIM (So IS and APIM trust each other) and then get the JWT from IS. Then use the JWT to get the access token from APIM. Then use this access token to access the APIs. You can follow [this](https://medium.com/wso2-learning/how-to-protect-your-apis-with-self-contained-access-token-jwt-using-wso2-api-manager-and-wso2-75673d8a4686) for the details.